# Print PHP array into table views with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm newbie in development and I have trouble with this below logic.

This is my sample DB.

```
$data = array(3) {
$x_count = 2;
[1] =>  $name = 'A';
        $y_count = 2;
        array(2) {
            [1] =>  $name = 'A.1';
                    $z_count = 2;
                    array(2) {
                        [1] =>  $name = 'A.1.a';
                                $val = 1;
                        [2] =>  $name = 'A.1.b';
                                $val = 1;
                    }
            [2] =>  $name = 'A.2';
                    $z_count = 2;
                    array(2) {
                        [1] =>  $name = 'A.2.a';
                                $val = 2;
                        [2] =>  $name = 'A.2.b';
                                $val = 2;
                    }
        }
[2] =>  $name = 'B';
        $y_count = 2;
        array(2) {
            [1] =>  $name = 'B.1';
                    $z_count = 2;
                    array(2) {
                        [1] =>  $name = 'B.1.a';
                                $val = 3;
                        [2] =>  $name = 'B.1.b';
                                $val = 3;
                    }
            [2] =>  $name = 'A.2';
                    $z_count = 2;
                    array(2) {
                        [1] =>  $name = 'B.2.a';
                                $val = 4;
                        [2] =>  $name = 'B.2.b';
                                $val = 4;
                    }
        }
}
```

And I have to print like this
[image]

I have no idea of using foreach loop to print data into this table or caculating the number of "colspan" for each of x, y, z title.

I really hope to receive some advice. Thanks a lot!

EDIT: the x_count, y_count and z_count are variables get from DB and it's not only 2.
EDIT2: my expected result looks like this:

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>x_name</th>
            <td colspan = "7">A</td>
            <td colspan = "7">B</td>
            <th rowspan = "3">SUM</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>y_name</th>
            <td colspan = "3">A.1</td>
            <td colspan = "3">A.2</td>
            <td rowspan = "2">SUM</td>
            <td colspan = "3">B.1</td>
            <td colspan = "3">B.2</td>
            <td rowspan = "2">SUM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>z_name</th>
            <td>A.1.a</td>
            <td>A.1.b</td>
            <td>SUM</td>
            <td>A.2.a</td>
            <td>A.2.b</td>
            <td>SUM</td>
            <td>B.1.a</td>
            <td>B.1.b</td>
            <td>SUM</td>
            <td>B.2.a</td>
            <td>B.2.b</td>
            <td>SUM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>value</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: First I think you should try to create a html table have the same structure like that, and then think about apply PHP to that html later

Comment: You can take a look at this link `https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/` for the idea of rowspan/colspan in table

Comment: @ThienHuynh mình create xong html rồi nhưng nhìn vào ko biết apply PHP kiểu gì nữa hức

Comment: @ThienHuynh index của mỗi array nó khác nhau nên mình ko biết làm sao để làm logic tổng quát hết trơn ...

Comment: ông update code phía trên đi, kèm theo html vô

Comment: @ThienHuynh tại là mình test cho hết count = 2 để tạo nên nó ra vậy chứ mình chưa viết đc vòng lặp. đưa cái xác table lên vậy thấy nó ngu si lắm hic

Comment: Tức là x_name số lượng cột có nhiều hơn A, B luôn à ?

Comment: @ThienHuynh vâng đúng rồi số lượng x->y->z là chưa có sẵn nó get từ DB á tùy mỗi điều kiện get lại khác nhau ạ...

Comment: Bạn cứ đưa html lên trên này mình xem, html cho 2 cái tạm thời như cái hình trên cũng đc

Comment: bạn up snipet html lên á

Comment: skype mình: live:thienhuynh8995. Tại vì đằng nào bạn cũng phải up html lên, không thì không ai giúp bạn làm đâu. Vì gặp nhiều vấn đề lắm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add y_count, x_count, you can use `count()` function on the object `$data` instead.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/du2t9fzn/1/) is HTML's structure I created, you may take a look

For data easier to process, you can consider to use my data structure below

```
$data = [
    [
        "name" => 'A', // x_name
        "children" => [
            [
                "name" => 'A.1', // y_name
                "children" => [
                    [
                        "name" => 'A.1.a', // z_name
                        "value" => 1
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
];
```

**NOTE: All the code's logic below is used for your provided HTML, not for my jsFiddle's HTML**

**First step**: Run a loop on every element of array $data for processing `x_name` data. Assign each row's html to variable for further use

```
/* Init html variable for $x_name, $y_name, $z_name, $value */
$x_html = '';
$y_html = '';
$z_html = '';
$value_html = '';
foreach ($data as $x_index => $x_data) {
    $x_children = $x_data['children'];
    $x_colspan = 1; // this variable will be sum of 1 'SUM' column and each $y_colspan
    foreach ($x_children as $y_index => $y_data) {
        $y_children = $x_data['children'];
        $y_colspan = count($y_children) + 1; // all of y's children column + SUM column

        // Update x_colspan
        $x_colspan += $y_colspan;

        // process assign html to $y_html
        $y_html .= '<td colspan = "'.$y_colspan.'">'.$y_data['name'].'</td>';
        // add SUM column
        if ($y_index == count($x_children)-1) {
            $y_html .= '<td>SUM</td>';
        }

        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($y_children as $z_index => $z_data) {
            $z_value = $z_data['value'];
            $z_html .= '<td>'.$z_data['name'].'</td>';
            // add SUM column for every looped 2 $z_data column
            if ($z_index == count($y_children)-1) {
                $z_html .= '<td>SUM</td>';
            }

            $sum += $z_value; // sum all value of current y_children
            $value_html .= '<td>'.$z_data['value'].'</td>';
        }
        // After finish assign z_html, value_html, sum it all
        $value_html .= '<td>'.$sum.'</td>'
    }


    $x_html .= '<td colspan = "'.$x_colspan.'">'.$x_data['name'].'</td>';
}
```

**Last step**: you print out all variable x_html, y_html, z_html, value_html. Merge it with the actual table html

```
$table_html = '
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>x_name</th>
        '.$x_html.'
        <th rowspan = "3">SUM</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>y_name</th>
        '.$y_html.'
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>z_name</th>
        '.$z_html.'
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>z_name</th>
        '.$value_html.'
    </tr>
</table>
';
```

This code above may be not runable, it's just a idea. Hope it would help you